# Disable application update notification

Tags: google-play-store, nexus-one, cyanogenmod

How can I disable certain application's update? I'm using Brut Google Map v4.6.0.4686. Since there is a new version in the market, the update notification will appear from time to time. How do I disable it?

Comment: I only receive notifications the first time an app has an update.  After that it just sits in the market's "My Apps" list with red text showing there's an update, even if the app is updated more times after that.

Comment: Try rebooting your phone, it'll reappear again

Comment: I reboot my phone lots.  What version of the Market do you have?

Comment: I think it's version 4. The one before Google changed the whole UI market. I'm using CM 6.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to disable market update notifications for a single app right now.

In order to disable update notifications for **all** apps in the Market, open the market app, press the MENU button, choose SETTINGS.

In the Notification drop down, select DO NOT NOTIFY ME.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed I can disable market>menu button>settings>Notification checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running cm 6.1 as well and I have a bug in my market that if you have, may solve your problem. My app updates get stuck sometimes and I've noticed if I cancel. An update the app no longer shows up as needs to be updated, or even installed, although it stays in my dl list. You could try starting the update then cancelling mid download. For me these apps in limbo don't give the update notification.

Comment: Seriously? I think I've had (sort of) similar experience, my internet connection had a problem during the update process, so, the app cannot be updated which causes the app to disappear from the list (I think Android uninstall the app before downloading the update).

Comment: Yeah, I'm serious.  It might just be a bug on my phone. The market is very wonky for me.  Every single time I update my apps, at least one gets hung up and I have to cancel it.  When I do it shows up as a new app, not installed even though it is still installed.  Strangely enough, even though it says it's not installed and stops giving me update notifications its still in my downloads list.  All I have to do to actually update it is to click on "install."